# NPP + Python: Move Text between search strings to Another Position (Footer)

Tags: python, regex, notepad++

I am working on sone html-documents looking like this:

```
<html>
    <head>Something in here</head>
    <body>
        <MYTAG>This should be moved to the Footer</MYTAG>
        <MYTAG>This should be moved to the Footer, too</MYTAG>
    </body>
    <footer></footer>
</html>
```

I am already using Notepad++ and Python to customize the rest of the document mainly using Regular Expressions.
Now I want to move the parts that are tagged with `<MYTAG></MYTAG>` to the footer, having the documents like this in the end:

```
<html>
    <head>Something in here</head>
    <body>
    </body>
    <footer>
        <MYTAG>This should be moved to the Footer</MYTAG>
        <MYTAG>This should be moved to the Footer, too</MYTAG>
    </footer>
</html>
```

First I tried to do the job with Regular Expressions alone:
Search for:
`(<html.*?)(<MYTAG>.*?</MYTAG>)(.*?<footer>)(.*?)(</footer>.*?</html>)`
and replace it with: `$1$3$4$2$5`
This works, but I have to run it over and over again for multiple `<MYTAG>`-parts (and it's a pain... with larger documents).

I know there is a better solution with python but I cannot get the coding write. The documentation and Syntax confuses me. I thought about using `editor.setSelection` followed by `editor.cut` and finally `editor.paste` somewhere to the footer but I don't know how to set the right targets.

Any help on this is very much appreciated :)

Comment: No need for regex, you can use BeautifulSoup, and I suppose it will be much faster.

Comment: Agree on that. BeautifulSoup it. Mush simpler and much faster.

Comment: This looks promising. I have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following script:

```
import re

with open("temp.html") as html_file:
    html = html_file.read()

tags = re.findall(r"<MYTAG>.*</MYTAG>\n*", html)

html = re.sub(r"<MYTAG>.*</MYTAG>\n*", "", html)

footer = re.split(r"<footer>", html)

tags.insert(0, "<footer>\n")
tags.insert(0, footer[0])
tags.append(footer[1])


with open("temp.html", "w") as html_file:
    html_file.write("".join(tags))
```

It working following way:

1. Read file
2. Finds all tags
3. Replaces tags in the body
4. Split file's content on 2 parts.
5. Adds the tags and `<footer>` in the text
6. Writes result to the file.

Comment: Running this gives me this error: `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'temp.html'`

Comment: @M.Minus Of course it's not exist, all right. You have to type path to your file instead of "temp.html". 

Just in case documentation about the with [link](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)

Comment: Ahh. I ran it at the wrong place. Works just fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(<html.*?)((?:\s*<MYTAG>[^<]+<\/MYTAG>\n*)+)(.*?( *)<footer>)(.*?)(<\/footer>.*?<\/html>)
```

Substitution:

```
\1\3\2\4\6
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wL9sT1/1)

Input

```
<html>
    <head>Something in here</head>
    <body>
        <MYTAG>This should be moved to the Footer</MYTAG>
        <MYTAG>This should be moved to the Footer, too</MYTAG>
    </body>
    <footer></footer>
</html>
```

Output

```
<html>
    <head>Something in here</head>
    <body>    </body>
    <footer>
        <MYTAG>This should be moved to the Footer</MYTAG>
        <MYTAG>This should be moved to the Footer, too</MYTAG>
    </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works quite fine, but fails in htmls with more content between the two `<MYTAG>`-strings. Would this still be solvable with RegEx and something like `<html>
    <head>Something in here</head>
    <body>
        <MYTAG>This should be moved to the Footer</MYTAG> Combobreaking content here.
        <MYTAG>This should be moved to the Footer, too</MYTAG>
    </body>
    <footer></footer>
</html>`